# System Tray only (no dock icon) application using C# / Mono on Mac

Tags: c#, macos, mono, background, system-tray

I'm looking to move one of my C# applications over to Mono for use on the Mac. Currently, I'm trying to figure out how to make it a sort of "background" process, but still have the ability to have GUI elements (I believe this rules out `mono-service`).

The ultimate goal is this:

1. Put a tray icon up by the clock for the majority of interactions.
2. **Remove** the dock icon that typically comes with a launched application
3. Have the application run on startup.

In short, just think of how the [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/referrals/NTIzNTY4NjY5?src=global0) app works. I want that type of GUI, but with a Mono / Mac app.

I believe this is typically accomplished by setting `LSUIElement = 1` in the application bundle's Info.plist. However, I've had no luck with it. I think it may have something to do with the `mono` command launching my application from within the app bundle. Once the app launches `mono` I'm assuming it doesn't cascade to further application launches. That is a pure guess, though.

Does anyone have any ideas on this? Thanks.

Comment: You might have more success if you mentioned the toolkit you're using.

Comment: I was trying to use GTK#. I don't think this is possible though.

Comment: You may want to look into MonoMac instead.  You'll have more of the native Mac OS X hooks available than you would with GTK#.

Comment: If I was revisiting this problem today, I probably would have broken this apart into two different applications. 1) A program for the status bar and 2) a program to communicate with the status bar (the background service). This would probably work around the issues I was having nearly 8 years ago.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have your answer:

First, to add a Status bar icon (alternative of Notify Icon in Win Forms):

```
        NSStatusItem sItem = NSStatusBar.SystemStatusBar.CreateStatusItem(30);
        sItem.Menu = notifyMenu;
        sItem.Image = NSImage.FromStream(System.IO.File.OpenRead(NSBundle.MainBundle.ResourcePath + @"/notify-icon.icns"));
        sItem.HighlightMode = true;
```

**notifyMenu** is your instance of NSMenu as a means of context menu strip for your notify icon.

and put your *ICNS* file made using **Icon Composer** in your project files and flag it as Content. (right click->build action->content)

Now It is time to remove dock icon:

on your info.plist file. make a new *Boolean* type item and name it "**LSUIElement**" and set the value to **YES**.

Hope it helps.
Regards,
Peyman Mortazavi

Comment: If anyone can confirm this, I'll mark it as best answer (I don't have the tools installed anymore)

Comment: I can confirm that it works on Yosemite with Xamarin Studio 5.8.2

Answer (score 0):

I do not know whether I understand your question properly. If you just need an application without any notion of main window, but with system tray, I once did it with WinForms using code like

```
static void Main()
{
    Application.Run(new MyContext());
}
```

Where `MyContext` was a class derived from `ApplicationContext` which in its constructor created a tray icon using `NotifyIcon` class. In fact `Application.Run()` starts message loop for your application giving tray icon a chance to answer user clicks (tray icon itself could be created earlier). It worked on Windows and Ubuntu, never tested on Mac.

Nevertheless today I would use Gtk# on Linux and MonoMac on Mac. In the first case concept is probably very similar (you can also see Tomboy code, it does exactly that!). In the second - don't know, never used it.