# TagLib port or similar audio tag reader for Java

Tags: java, audio, cross-platform, taglib

Does anyone know if there is a [TagLib](http://developer.kde.org/~wheeler/taglib.html) port or similar audio tag reader for available for Java? I am currently using TagLibSharp on C#, but I'm looking to go cross-platform.

I would really prefer to be using Mono, but I have [had problems with it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4414629/system-tray-only-no-dock-icon-application-using-c-mono-on-mac) and support for Mono on the Mac seems to be pretty lackluster.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have had the most success with [JAudiotagger](http://www.jthink.net/jaudiotagger/). It has a commercially friendly license and supports more formats than any other Java library I've found.

Comment: Looks excellent! Do you know if it has any support for AAC files?

Comment: I don't think it does, sorry.

Comment: Actaully it does support AAC files (mp4 files)